# navigation menu with bottom line

Tags: html, css

I am working on navigation menu, I want to design a menu which will look like following.

[image: the menu that i need is give]

my html code is give

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>WOMEN</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>MEN</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>JUNIOR</span></a></li>
    <li ><a href='#'><span>ACCESSORIES</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>COLLECTION</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>SALE</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href='#'><span>MY ACCOUNT</span></a></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

and my css is given

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  /*content: ' ';
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;*/

}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;

}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;

  border-bottom:10px solid #000 ;
}
.last {
float:right;
padding-left:60px;
font-style:italic;}


#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  border-color:#5ae1e4;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  border-color:#FFF;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  /*content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;*/
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
 /* content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;*/
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    height: 1px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .2;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

now my output is give

[image: The output resul]

now I want the black like till to en.. I means the with of the black like 100%.
I will be thankful if I have the ability to control the line with
Note: for me only css and html is allowed
thank you in advance

Comment: can you correct your spelling ? **now I want the black like till to en.. I means the with of the black like 100%.** what exactly do you need?

Comment: sorry for that, I want the black like on the bottom with 100% width. I want it like give in the demo pic. there is different in my work and in required work. both are given in the pic

Comment: Do you mean you want the black line to expand all the way to the right-hand side of the page?

Comment: I want to start it from the WOMEN with the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bkcG3/

here use the outside div with border

I made your li into display:inline-block

```
#cssmenu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 10px black solid;
height: 49px;
}
```

EDIT-

New fiddle with a css reset block to takecare of the extra spaces you been
seeing from some of the different browsers, and fixed the styles accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/bkcG3/1/

make sure to read

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: thank for ur kind help. if you see the current screen shot. as given in the following link.  http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yniTci36ouM/U6IV0QhrOZI/AAAAAAAAF14/gpgMAAOVWVI/s1600/abc.png  the tow lines are not same. means the height problem.

Comment: Hi, now all is OK. the only thing that i needed now to start the bottom line and text i.e WOMEN together. please help me in this